# How to create a mat-table with a checkbox and a label in the same column?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material-table, mat-select

I'm using Angular Material and I would like my first column to have a checkbox as well as the value of my `name`-property. I dont need this column to be sticky. I appreciate any ideas for this.

Under the following link you can find my stackblitz example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-table-checkbox-select-all-lbspiz?file=main.ts

I have tried to add a row span which did not work out.

Comment: You mean you want a checkbox and the `name` property in the same column?

Comment: @kellermat : yes correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I made a working example on stackblitz:

**[Stackblitz-Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-table-checkbox-select-all-n5tvqy?file=app%2Ftable-selection-example.ts,app%2Ftable-selection-example.html)**

I basically made the following changes to bring `select` and `name` in the same column:

The modified part of the **TS-File**:

```
displayedColumns: string[] = ['selectAndName', 'position', 'weight', 'symbol'];
```

The modified part of the **HTML-File**:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="selectAndName">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
    <mat-checkbox
      (change)="$event ? masterToggle() : null"
      [checked]="selection.hasValue() && isAllSelected()"
      [indeterminate]="selection.hasValue() && !isAllSelected()"
    >
    </mat-checkbox>
    Select and name
  </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
    <mat-checkbox
      (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
      (change)="$event ? selection.toggle(element) : null"
      [checked]="selection.isSelected(element)"
    >
    </mat-checkbox>
    {{element.name}}
  </td>
</ng-container>
```